# Multi Conditional Statements in R

Tags: r

I'd like to know the shape or length of the filtered dataframe through multiple conditions. I have 2 methods I've used, but I'm a little stumped because they're giving me different outputs.

1. Method 1

```
    x <- df[df$gender=='male',]    
    x <- x[x$stat == 0,]    
    nrow(x)    
    OUTPUT = Some Number
```

2. Method 2

```
    nrow(sqldf('SELECT * FROM df WHERE gender == "male" AND stat == 0'))    
    OUTPUT = Some Number
```

I'm a little confused as to why the outputs would be different? Any ideas?

Comment: I did add commas, just forgot to add it here. Method 1 is not an OR statement. The outputs are very close, but not the same. I figured it out. The sql command filters out NA values, while method 1 did not.

Comment: great, you can add it as an answer then since you solved it yourself.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include the commas, otherwise it just looks like your problem is bad syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in method one you assigned x to df[df$gender=='male'] and then you replace x with assigning it to x[x$stat == 0]. So you will end up with nrow for how many stat == 0 only. Off of the top of my head with no dataset, maybe x <- df[df$gender=='male' & x$stat == 0] would work.  Although I have never done it this way. I would use the subset function with x <- subset(x, df$gender=='male' & x$stat == 0) and then nrow(x).